# Can I upload an arduino code on Atmega8?

Tags: arduino

I have a arduino Duemilanove and an atmega8 chip. The arduino board is having Atmega328 on it. I have written a code that works fine on arduino. Now I want to transfer that code from arduino to my atmega8 chip. Can I use arduino bootloader to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To a degree, with care and appropriate support files - the earlier Arduino's used the Atmega8. However it has only 1/4 the memory of the current Atmega328p, and likely not all the peripherals, so many things may not be possible.  Cost advantage (if you can even find them) will be minimal until you get to huge volumes, so unless you have a lot of chips already soldered on legacy boards, why bother?  You'll need an ISP programmer (perhaps your 328p board), with which you can load a bootloader or directly load sketches.

Comment: I have 20 atmega8s actually. It is available at one third the price of atmega328, so definitely economical.

Answer (score 1):

In theory you can, but there are some things missing at Atmega8, like Timer2 hardware, for example.

So it is possible use the Atmega8, but you need to upload Arduino NG or older w/ ATmega8 bootloader to the chip and check your code (mind the libraries!) for use of hardware that is not present at Atmega8.

To burn the bootloader I am using a Parallel Cabe, like this:
http://arduino.cc/en/Hacking/ParallelProgrammer

And follow the sequence below to burn it:

1. Choose menu Tools > Boards > Arduino NG or older w/ ATmega8
2. Choose menu Tools > Programmer > Parallel Programmer
3. Menu Tools > Burn Bootloader

That's it!
Regards
Renato Aloi

Answer (score 0):

You Can use the old files from arduino for sure and (probably also the newer builds)
But keep in mind that you have only ~7Kb(after the 1K bootloader)

you will need to compile the code as "Arduino NG or older w/ Atmega8"

You can find instructions on how to burn a boot loader here
http://arduino.cc/en/Hacking/Bootloader

And a reference schematics here 
http://arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/arduino_NG_schematic.png